# How to download multiple files from a list of links using python requests?

Tags: python, automation, python-requests

I'm trying to download multiple mp3 files using Python's requests module from a list of links that I created, but for some reason it keeps giving me bad requests for every single link (it doesn't do this when I insert the link manually).

```
import requests as rq
HOR=[] #The list of links,it's actually a list not an empty list but it's too large
HOR_Names=[]
for i in range(189):
    print(HOR[i])
    doc=rq.get(HOR[i])
    print(doc.text)
    open(HOR_Names[i], 'wb').write(doc.content)
```

it gives me this error:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
<H2>Error 400</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You're probably being rate-limited by whatever site you're downloading from.

Comment: Type into the terminal the contents of the link you are submitting. Maybe there is something wrong with your link if it goes through manually.

Comment: Your error 400 itself is a bad request. It occurs when the user's browser sends an invalid request to the server where the site resides.

Comment: It downloads files from the links that were inserted manually, furthermore, isn't it supposed to download the files from the links consecutively? Like: every single link is downloaded independently?

Comment: @Евгений it works when I insert the link manually in the script instead of iterating over the list of links.

Comment: I mean, look at what you have inserted from the dictionary, the link in what form? Maybe it has the wrong form. But manually you insert everything correctly. Check what you have in the url.

Comment: @Евгений it's the exact same link, I even made the code print it in the terminal and copied it from there to input it manually just to be sure, still the same problem.

Comment: I think that to understand what is wrong, you need at least some links or site from where you do the download. Because it's hard to tell what's wrong with you. Everything seems to be correct in the code.